Open neighborhood of a geometric knot in an orientable 3-dimensional manifold.
I was reading "Braid Groups" by Christian Kassel and Vladimir Turaev where I found the following question: Prove that an arbitrary geometric knot $L$ in an orientable 3-dimensional manifold has an open neighbourhood $U \supset L$ such that the pair $(U, L)$ is homeomorphic to ($\mathbb R^{2} \times S^{1}, \{ x\} \times S^{1}$), where $x\in \mathbb R^{2}$.
What I know:
A manifold of dimension $n$ is a Hausdorff, second countable space such that neighborhood of every point of the space is homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb R^{n}$ (This property is called being locally Euclidean of dimension $n$).
A geometric link in a 3-dimensional topological manifold $M$(possibly with boundary $\delta$M) is a locally flat closed 1-dimensional submanifold of $M$.
A closed (compact and having empty boundary)1-dimensional manifold $L \subset M$ is said to be locally flat if every point of $L$ has a neighborhood $U \subset M$ such that the pair $(U , U \cap L)$ is homeomorphic to the pair ($\mathbb R^{3}, \mathbb R \times \{ 0\}\times \{ 0\}$)
Being a closed 1-dimensional submanifold, a geometric link $M$ must consist of a finite number of components homeomorphic to the standard unit circle. Now a geometric link consisting of only one component is said to be a geometric knot.
How do I proceed with the proof? Any hints...

How do they define orientation for topological manifolds?

As for a proof, it is somewhat painful. For locally flat submanifolds in topological manifolds, it was done by Morton Brown, see my answer here.

They did not define orientation for topological manifolds.

And I am not able to understand your answer

Then you should move on and skip this problem.

Step 1: define a continuously-varying everywhere non-zero normal vector field along the knot.  Step 2: Consider the unit tangent vector field of the knot.  This gives you a continuously-varying orthonormal pair along the knot, with one of the vectors tangent to the knot.  Step 3: Define a third vector field as the cross product of the previous two. Step 4: Tubular neighbourhood theorem.

This question sounds like it assumes some sophisticated knowledge of manifold topology. There is no loss of generality working with smooth knots, in which case this is just a direct application of the tubular neighborhood theorem which you'll find in any differential topology textbook.
